# Get values from DataFrame column without NaN pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I have a DF like this one:

```
        col1 col2
           1    4
         NaN    5
         NaN    3
           7    2
           8   10
           9   11
```

How can I get the first column from df as a list without NaN values:

```
col1_list = [1, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) with converting values to integers (if necessary) and then convert to list:

```
col1_list = df['col1'].dropna().astype(int).tolist()
print (col1_list)
[1, 7, 8, 9]
```